# How to retain a SQL DateTimeOffset in Snowflake without converting to UTC

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, utc, datetimeoffset, fivetran

In SQL Server I store a datetime as a DateTimeOffset data type so the table values contain the UTC offset. For Example:

```
2020-05-24 14:20:18.0000000 -05:00
```

However, once I import into Snowflake (via Fivetran) the value is converted to UTC. For Example:

```
2020-05-24 19:20:18.000 +0000
```

How can I maintain the source value after importing into Snowflake without converting to UTC?

Comment: Hi  - what is the data type of the target column?

Comment: TIMESTAMP_TZ so I would have expected it to be preserved but it was not.

Comment: I would look at what Fivetran is doing with the data. Is it recognising that the source  data has a timezone offset? Are you doing any transformation to the data?

Comment: what is the default timezone on your account, user, and session?  Is it possible that your account is displaying using UTC, because that's the default?

Comment: Not doing any transformations on the data. I'm checking with Fivetran and will let you know. Thank you.

Comment: If both the source and target columns are data types that support timezone offsets then it sounds like the issue is actually in the way Fivetran is handling the data. Some ETL products will convert everything to UTC internally so a standard timestamp/datetime data construct can be used.

Comment: It was indeed Fivetran:
According to our documentation here, specifically:
Fivetran initially converts source timestamps to UTC and then loads them into your destination as UTC.


 the conversion you are seeing is expected behavior.

You could then convert the value to your desired time zone for analysis purposes.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that Snowflake has 3 different timezone types, including
`TIMESTAMP_LTZ` and `TIMESTAMP_TZ`.

> - TIMESTAMP_LTZ stores UTC time with a specified precision
> - TIMESTAMP_TZ  stores UTC time together with an associated time zone offset

Use `TIMESTAMP_TZ` to store the associated time zone offset.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/data-types-datetime.html#timestamp-ltz-timestamp-ntz-timestamp-tz

Comment: The column created upon initial import was TIMESTAMP_TZ but the values have been converted.

Comment: Maybe the info was lost in translation? What happens if you ingest the same data without Fivetran? If this works, there might be a setting on Fivetran

Comment: I'm checking with Fivetran and will let you know. Thank you.

Comment: It was indeed Fivetran: According to our documentation here, specifically: Fivetran initially converts source timestamps to UTC and then loads them into your destination as UTC. the conversion you are seeing is expected behavior. You could then convert the value to your desired time zone for analysis purposes.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: Glad to know! Please accept the answer if it was useful to you :)